# Player Score not being updated on the TextMeshPro component

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just created a TextMeshPro Text component and then instantaneously created a PreFab out of it. I then attached this prefab to the script(by dragging it in the Serialized field) where the brick is being destroyed where I am updating the text by the .text attribute.

When I Debug.Log() the score.text, it gives me the correct value. But the score on the UI remains 0. There are no errors being raised and I have cross checked the code multiple times.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    [SerializeField] LevelScript levelScript;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip clip;
    static int gameScore;
    private void Start()
    {
        gameScore = 0;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // PlayClipAtPoint creates a temporary gameObject that is created in the world space so that
        // the sound keeps on playing even though the gameobject is deleted or destroyed
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, Camera.main.transform.position);
        gameScore += 83;
        scoreText.text = gameScore.ToString();
        Destroy(gameObject);        
        Debug.Log("Object name: " + collision.gameObject.name);
        Debug.Log("GameScore: " + gameScore);
        Debug.Log("Frame Count: " + Time.frameCount);       
        Debug.Log(scoreText.text);
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Object name: Ball
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 
GameScore: 83
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 
Frame Count: 162
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 
Object name: Ball
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 
GameScore: 166
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 
Frame Count: 337
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

Also, I noticed that only a prefab can be dragged on a serializedfield of a prefab and not a normal gameobject. Please help me out on this one and let me know if you require any additional information on this matter.

Also on the image that is attached below, you can see that after I stop playing the game, the score is displayed 747. But during the gameplay, the score is 0.

So in a nutshell, the score is not updated while playing the game but only after I have stopped the play button is when I see the final score.

UI:

[image: Unity Editor UI]

Comment: why is your gameScore static? and no, prefab is not required to drop it on a serializedfield. What could happen here is that SerializedField is needed to see your private variables on the editor. Make those variables public and tell me if now you can drop it non-prefab gameObjects. Also keep in mind that static fields won't show on Editor.

Comment: @Lotan, I made the gameScore static as I wanted the score to not turn back to 0 when the next level is loaded. Just doing some trial and error stuff. I made it a normal variable. Now, the text should be updated to 83 after hitting a block, but the text remains 0 in the UI. Correct me if I'm wrong but since I am destroying the block object, is it the culprit somehow? Lastly, I tried dropping a normal textmeshpro object in the Serialized Field of the block prefab and it's not allowing for me to do so. I have to drop a prefab of scoreText only.

Comment: I think there is something else in your code/project. This debug logs after the Destroy command should be called before Destroy. The problem droping your prefab should not exist, the only thing I can think of is that your definition of "normal textMeshPro object" differs from mine.

Comment: @Lotan by normal, I meant the way we all drop a textmeshpro object as a child of the Canvas

Comment: nevermind, I think I get you now, you were trying to say: attach it to a PREFAB on the prefab directories, not on a prefab already instantiated on the scene, right? If yes, then you're right, you need another prefab to link it to an existent (in your project, not scene) prefab. Anyways what you can do is, when instanciating your blocks, make a reference to your text on runtime.

Comment: @Lotan by runtime, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219958/discussion-between-lotan-and-rishab-parmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here was a bad reference.

Instead of referencing the scene `Score` objet, the reference was pointing to the Editor prefab, not the one currently instantiated on the scene.

One quick solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    [SerializeField] LevelScript levelScript;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip clip;
    static int gameScore;
    private void Start()
    {
        gameScore = 0;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // PlayClipAtPoint creates a temporary gameObject that is created in the world space so that
        // the sound keeps on playing even though the gameobject is deleted or destroyed
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, Camera.main.transform.position);
        gameScore += 83;

        //Find the scene reference
        scoreText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ScoreText");
        
        scoreText.text = gameScore.ToString();

        Debug.Log("Object name: " + collision.gameObject.name);
        Debug.Log("GameScore: " + gameScore);
        Debug.Log("Frame Count: " + Time.frameCount);       
        Debug.Log(scoreText.text);

        Destroy(gameObject);                
    }
}
```

Another one, to avoid the `FindByTag` method (an expensive one) is to simply drag and drop Score gameObject to the blocks `scoreText` variable.